# Keras: AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I want to compile my DQN Agent but I get error:
`AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_name'`,

```
DQN = buildAgent(model, actions)
DQN.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
```

I tried adding fake `_name` but it doesn't work, I'm following a tutorial and it works on tutor's machine, it's probably some new update change but how to fix this

Here is my full code:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import gym
from keras.optimizer_v1 import Adam
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

episodes = 10

def buildModel(statez, actiones):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, statez)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actiones, activation='linear'))
    return model

model = buildModel(states, actions)

def buildAgent(modell, actionz):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=modell, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actionz, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

DQN = buildAgent(model, actions)
DQN.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

Comment: add full code, this code doesn't any error

Comment: @I'mahdi okay, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error came from importing `Adam` with `from keras.optimizer_v1 import Adam`, You can solve your problem with `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` from `TensorFlow >= v2` like below:

*(The `lr` argument is deprecated, it's better to use `learning_rate` instead.)*

```
# !pip install keras-rl2
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import gym
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n
episodes = 10

def buildModel(statez, actiones):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, statez)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actiones, activation='linear'))
    return model

def buildAgent(modell, actionz):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=modell, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                   nb_actions=actionz, nb_steps_warmup=10, 
                   target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

model = buildModel(states, actions)
DQN = buildAgent(model, actions)
DQN.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents: use legacy keras optimizer!

```
#from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
```

it works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

#pip install keras==2.11.0

#pip install tensorflow==2.11.0

`dqn.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])`