# shape mismatch in deep learning model

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have the following code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import gym
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n
episodes = 10

def buildModel(statez, actiones):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, statez)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actiones, activation='linear'))
    return model
def buildAgent(modell, actionz):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=modell, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                   nb_actions=actionz, nb_steps_warmup=10,
                   target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn
model = buildModel(states, actions)
DQN = buildAgent(model, actions)
DQN.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
DQN.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

It is taken from given resource : [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894769/keras-attributeerror-adam-object-has-no-attribute-name)

but when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2)
Training for 50000 steps ...
Interval 1 (0 steps performed)
```

I can not understand how I am getting the shape (1,2), please help me.

Comment: try to change this line from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
 to from keras.optimizers import Adam